# No android devices supporting FEATURE_CAMERA_EXTERNAL

Tags: android, camera, android-camera2

According to [this doc](https://source.android.com/devices/camera/external-usb-cameras) some android devices allows accessing external usb cameras using Camera2 API. I checked around 10 samsung phones (Galaxy Tab S4/7, Galaxy A71, Galaxy S10e). None of them have FEATURE_CAMERA_EXTERNAL.

```
if(packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_EXTERNAL)) {
   Log.v("TestApp", "Supports external camera")
}
else {
   Log.v("TestApp", "Doesnt support external camera")
}
```

Does anyone know what devices support FEATURE_CAMERA_EXTERNAL?

Comment: I heard, Samsung S10e supports it

Comment: The Zora P1 dev board supports it.