# Any Android phones supporting FEATURE_CAMERA_EXTERNAL?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I am looking for any Android mobile phone that supports external USB cameras natively using Camera2 API based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68097064/no-android-devices-supporting-feature-camera-external).

This is a follow up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68097064/no-android-devices-supporting-feature-camera-external) in 2021, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57846505/accessing-a-usb-camera-using-android-camera2-api) in 2019.

Any input is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

It was mentioned that Samsung S10e was capable but I just bought one and unfortunately `packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_EXTERNAL)` returns `false` on the device.

Comment: Also looking for this. Would be really cool if there was a list of mobile devices and specs(android hw support) somewhere...